# problems with singularity $0$ of $\int_{W} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{(z-3)^3} dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the complex integral 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{W} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{(z-3)^3} dz 
\end{equation*}
where $W$ is a circle with radius $6$ and centered at $0$.

Obviously we have two singularities, one in $0$ and one in $3$. I only get confused by the singularity in $0$. I don't clearly see what $\lim_{z\rightarrow0}$ of $zf(z)$ is. the limit $ze^\frac{1}{z}$ bothers me a lot and l'hopital does not provide a clear result.

Any tips?

Kees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an essential singularity at $0$, so $z^k\cdot f(z)$ has no limit at $0$, for any $k$.

In principle, you could develop $\frac{1}{(z-3)^3}$ into a geometric series around $0$, multiply that with the series for $e^{1/z}$, and find a series representation of the residue at $0$ in that way. That would however be a lot of work, where mistakes can easily be made.

But you can also use Cauchy's integral theorem to shift the contour. The integral

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3}\,dz$$

is for $R > 3$ independent of $R$. For $R \geqslant 6$ and $\lvert z\rvert = R$, we have $\lvert z-3\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert - 3 \geqslant \frac{R}{2}$, and since $\lvert e^{1/z}\rvert \leqslant e^{1/\lvert z\rvert}$, we find

$$\Biggl\lvert \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3}\,dz\Biggr\rvert \leqslant 2\pi R\frac{8e^{1/R}}{R^3} \leqslant \frac{16\pi e^{1/6}}{R^2}$$

by the standard estimate, so

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3}\,dz = 0.$$

Since the integral doesn't depend on $R$,

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3}\,dz = 0$$

for all $R > 3$.

More conceptually, if you are familiar with the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, we can view the circle $\lvert z\rvert = 6$ as the boundary curve of $G = \widehat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 6\}$, and the residue theorem then says

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3}\,dz = -2\pi i \sum_{\zeta\in G} \operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3};\zeta\biggr) = -2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3}; \infty\biggr).$$

The minus sign comes from the orientation of the circle, $G$ lies to the right of the circle. Since by definition

$$\operatorname{Res}(f(z);\infty) = \operatorname{Res}\biggl(-\frac{1}{z^2}f\biggl(\frac{1}{z}\biggr); 0\biggr),$$

we compute

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-3)^3};\infty\biggr)
&= \operatorname{Res}\Biggl(-\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{e^z}{\bigl(\frac{1}{z}-3\bigr)^3}; 0\Biggr)\\
&= \operatorname{Res}\biggl(-\frac{ze^z}{(1-3z)^3};0\biggr)\\
&= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: yesm, it is $2\pi \cdot (\sum Res_{z=a_j} f(z))$. The main problem though is that i cannot calculate the resiudu of the point zero because it is essential as you already said :). Does this mean that this integral does not exist?

Kees

Comment: Can you *estimate* the integral?

Comment: no i don't know how? we can try to remove 0 but i cannot just do that right...?

Comment: You know that $$\left\lvert\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right\rvert \leqslant L(\gamma)\cdot \max \{ \lvert f(\gamma(t))\rvert \},$$ I'm sure. Now, for a suitable $R$ ... can you see where it's going?

Comment: Expand the integrand in a Laurent-series. Then you can read off the residue from the coefficient $a_{-1}$ of the series. For an example see [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Example)

Comment: @gst Expanding this integrand in a Laurent series isn't too nice, we have a much simpler way here.

Comment: @daniel fisher, i tried that. but I don't see whether $e^1/z$ goes faster to infinity than R^9 (for R-->\infty)

Comment: @KeesTil $e^{1/z} \to e^0 = 1$ for $z\to\infty$. The integrand is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{z^3}$ for $z\to\infty$. I've added an estimation of the integral, and an interpretation in terms of the residue at $\infty$. The latter has the advantage that it also works if we don't have an integrand decaying sufficiently fast to use the standard estimate (although in such cases computing the residue at $\infty$ can also be non-trivial, so "works" is to be taken cautiously).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{W} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{(z-3)^3} dz $$

$$=2\pi i[Res(f,0)+Res(f,3)]=-2\pi iRes(f,\infty)=0$$where , $f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{(z-3)^3} $. Since, sum of residues at finite poles and the residue at $\infty$ is equal to zero.

Since,  $Res(f,\infty)=-\lim_{z\to \infty}zf(z)$ , as $f(\infty)=0$

$=-\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{z}{(z-3)^3}e^{1/z}=0$.